# Why I can't cast Integer to String?

Tags: java, string, casting, integer

I get this error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String at line "case 0". why I can't cast Integer to String and how to solve this error ?

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {

    switch (column) {
            case 0: user.get(row).setId(Integer.parseInt((String)value)); break;
            case 1: user.get(row).setUsername((String)value); break;
            case 2: user.get(row).setPassowrd((String)value); break;
            case 3: user.get(row).setEmail((String)value); break;
 
            
    }

    this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, row);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?  An integer is a number, and a string is text.  They're 2 different things.  `Integer.parseInt()` takes an integer and parses it into a string representation of a number.  There's no need for any casting here.

Comment: You can not cast `"Hello"` to an `int`.

Comment: Charlie Armstrong I am trying to retrieve the user id value from a method which updates the table. I am using Table Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user.get(row).setId(Integer.parseInt(**String.valueOf(value)**));

Comment: This makes no sense at all. If `String.valueOf` converts the object `value` to a `String` such that it can be parsed as an `Integer`, then it must have been an `Integer` to begin with.

Comment: @WJS - You are spot on! Akif Hadziabdic, if `value` is an `Integer`, you can simply cast it to `Integer`, the way [WJS has done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66054911/10819573); why do you need to call these two methods unnecessarily?

Comment: of course, we have to check type in order to improve performances, but if the value is "1" cast will not help because the input is a type of Object

Comment: But it isn't a String.  Otherwise, (String)value would have worked in the OP's example.  Besides, the `ClassCastException` says specifically that value is an Integer.

Comment: I agree code can be improved, but an input type is an object, the method is public, an instance of class Car ( String toString() { return "Car"}) can be the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> get this error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String at line "case 0"

From the error it looks to me that Object is already an Integer.  So just do the following:

```
user.get(row).setId((Integer)value);
```

**A quick demo:**

```
Object a = 10;
int x = (Integer) a;
System.out.println(x);
```